# Configuring the Node Identifier Option in Exhaustive CHAID in SPSS Data Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

According to IBM's [online help](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS3RA7_18.2.0/modeler_mainhelp_client_ddita/clementine/treerule_general.html):

> - Optionally, for CHAID, QUEST, and C&R Tree models, an additional field can be added that indicates the ID for the node to which each record is assigned.

I cannot find that option. I am using an (exhaustive) CHAID which adds the $R- (prediction field) variable but there is no $RI- (node identifier field) variable. Just in case IBM was being literal I checked running a regular CHAID (not exhaustive) but still without getting the $RI-variable I need.

I know that in SPSS v. 25 this is easily configured so is IBM just confused in their online help for modeler, or am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get the rule identifier added to the data set, you need to first train the model to generate the model nugget.
You can then edit (or open) the model nugget and select the "Settings" tab. Here you will find the option "Rule identifier" which must be checked to include the ID of node the each record is assigned.

[image: Settings tab from Model Nugget]

It is important to realize that this is a setting in the generated mudel nugget and not in the modeling node. This also means that this setting must be checked (and rechecked) each time the model is retrained and the nugget is regenerated.

Comment: Thank you very much Kenneth. Just for posterity, if using splits in the CHAID it's necessary to generate the model nugget for each split as well.

Comment: @DrL You are correct.
The 'Rule Identifier' option is not available in any of the decision tree model nuggets, if the nugget contains multiple models such as it would when using one or more fields to split the data set.